# List form - how can I allow the users to select approval workflow?

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, form, approval

I have a simple form in a SharePoint list. This consists of a few text fields, check boxes, radio buttons, and a "comments" text box. A user must be able to fill out the form and save it. It should then go to additional people for comments. However, I want the USER to be able to select which approval workflow is used.

If I create some workflows in SharePoint Designer, am I able to allow the user to select one of these workflows right in the form? How would I do this? The idea is that the following people in the workflow will just add their comments to the "comments" box with perhaps a date and their initials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one workflow that contains IF statements to test the value of the field on the form and execute the appropriate business logic.

Let's say you have a field named **Approval Workflow** on your form with the following values: Workflow 1, Workflow 2, Workflow 3. Inside your workflow you can have 3 IF statements, each one testing for one of the values of the **Approval Workflow** field. Given that you can only pick only one value in the field, then only one of the IF statements will execute.

I hope this makes sense.